# Multithreading WMI calls - how best to handle this?

Tags: multithreading, .net-4.0, backgroundworker

Hi I need to send a WMI query to each system in a domain (potentially thousands), and WMI queries seem to take a long time to return. So I am reviewing the best ways to send multiple requests using multiple threads, so the process can run in the background and the calls can overlap.

I like the features that BackgroundWorker offers, and I read [HERE](http://cs.rthand.com/blogs/blog_with_righthand/archive/2006/05/26/725.aspx) that it uses the ThreadPool under the covers. I dont really understand though how I would leverage this to serve my purposes. It seems that if I had to send 1000 queries, I could do a loop in which I invoke a new BG worker for each query, and the threadpool will use up to 25(?) threads at one time, and the remaining 975 requests are queued. Is that what happens?

If this is right, I imagine the process of queuing up 1000 requests will itself freeze the UI, so should the queuing loop itself be running in another BG worker?

Is there a problem with invoking other worker threads from a worker thread?

Should I be only creating say 20 BG worker threads and manually launching another when one completes?

Am I understanding this right? Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the Parallel.ForEach method found in the System.Threading.Tasks namespace.

Make a List<string> containing all the host names you want to query. Then make a method that takes a string as it's input and queries it and does whatever it is you're wanting to do with that data.

Put them in a ForEach method like this

```
Parallel.ForEach(ComputerList, QueryAComputer);
```

and let it rip. Be sure to call the Dispose() method on ManagementObjects as soon as you don't need them. I think there's some kind of issue that causes WMI to break when too many queries are performed at once. Dispose() should help release those resources and prevent deadlock.